# android support v4 library not supported in android 4.0 but working in 5.0?

Tags: android, xml, drawerlayout

The Drawer layout not supported in android 4.0 version and if android-support-v4.jar file adding then multiple dex file error occur.

I am facing this problem from last friday. Please help me.

**xml**

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--android:layout_below="@+id/topLay"
     android:layout_above="@+id/menu_lay" -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/dList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/menu_divider_color"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/divider_ht"
        android:background="@drawable/side_menu_bg"/>
    <!-- android:layout_width="220dp" -->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**gradle file**

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(':facebook')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.3.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
//for multiple dex library
compile files('libs/PdfViewer.jar')
compile project(':mupdflibrary')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.3.2'
compile project(':gesture-imageview')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: 
 main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tatahousing/com.tatahousing.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
     at com.tatahousing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:227)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267) 
     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895) 
     at com.tatahousing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:227) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs
     at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateIcsImpl.newAccessiblityDelegateDefaultImpl(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:122)
     at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat.<clinit>(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:302)
     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.<init>(DrawerLayout.java:175)
     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.<init>(DrawerLayout.java:347)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267) 
     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895) 
     at com.tatahousing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:227) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If you have a multiple dex file error, please include your list of dependencies.

Comment: can you post your gradle, your manifest and most importantly the actual error you are getting. Your post is not at all clear and does not provide enough information for us to fix the issue.

Comment: show your error plz :D

Comment: I update the code with dependencies and error that I am getting while executing in android 4.4.4 version

Answer (score 0):

Add following dependency in your app gradle file and remove externa jar file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
```

Comment: Already remove all other files. Now add the same dependency suggested by you in my gradle file. Let see it solves the issue or not.